# Reproducir Audio en JS

Tags: javascript, audio

Quiero reproducir un audio desde javascript al momento de cargar la página sin necesidad de acción del usuario. En sí es una playlist, y todo se carga de forma dinámica:

```
 var audio = document.createElement("audio");
 /*
 ... etc
 */

 selectTrack(index){
     audio.src = urls[index];
     audio.load();
     audio.play();
 }


 selectTrack(0); //Auto play
```

Al cargar la página no funciona la primera llamada automática.

Comment: ¿Que error muestra?

Comment: Antes de ejecutar esta línea `selectTrack(0);`, debes asegurarte que la variable **urls** tenga un valor (en este caso un arreglo).

¿Cómo le estas asignando el valor a **urls**?